# Convert .pt to .pth?

Tags: python, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, yolov5

I've been trying to compile my custom trained YoloV5 model using SageMaker Neo.
The compilation gives an error :

```
ClientError: InputConfiguration: No pth file found for PyTorch model. 
Please make sure the framework you select is correct.
```

The weights are a `.pt` file.
Is there a way to convert the `.pt` file to `.pth`?

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between both file extensions. If SageMaker is only looking for a file with a `.pth` extension, then you can simply rename your file from `filename.pt` to `filename.pth`.

Comment: That does not seem to work, I get the error message ```ClientError: InputConfiguration: Framework cannot load PyTorch model. No module named 'models'```

Comment: I think that is an unrelated error